# How to solve this integral

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Wolfram integrator is unable to solve this:

> $$
>  \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt {(a-\cos(t))^2+(b-\sin(t))^2+c^2}}\,\mathrm dt
> $$

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This is an elliptic integral. You can rewrite it as 2.571 in the compendium by Gradshteyn/Ryzhik.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $(a-\cos(t))^2 + (b-\sin(t))^2 + c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 1 - 2(a \cos(t) + b \sin(t))$.

Also note that $a \cos (t) + b \sin(t) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin (t + F)$.

Let $d = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 1$ and $e = 2\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Then, our integral becomes

$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{d - e \sin(t + F)}}\mathrm dt$, where $d,e$, and $F$ are constants. This is elliptic and has no simple solution in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

This can be rewritten

$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +1 - 2a \cos t - 2b \sin t}} dt
$

which has the form

$
A \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + B \sin(t+\phi)}} dt
$

for appropriate constants $A$, $B$, and $\phi$. I just tried the indefinite integral

$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + B \sin(t+\phi)}} dt
$

in Wolfram Alpha. It provided a closed form answer.

I hope this helps.